# How To Display Laravel Breeze Status Message

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel Breeze for authentication, and I'm facing a problem:

When user request a password reset link, I like to show him/her a success message, if we send email successfully. PasswordResetLinkController returns this:

```
return $status == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
    ? back()->with('status', __($status))
    : back()->withInput($request->only('email'))
            ->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
```

When it goes back, it goes, for example, to home route. HomeController returns home.blade.php. When I try to display $status, which should be passed by PasswordResetLinkController, I got undefiened variable error. How can I get that message?

**EDIT**

PasswordResetLinkController.php

```
// This is the original store function came with Breeze.
// I did touch neither code nor the comments.
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
       'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
    // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
    // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
    $status = Password::sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );
    return $status == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
       ? back()->with('status', __($status))
       : back()->withInput($request->only('email'))
               ->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
}
```

HomeController.php

```
public function index()
{
   $baseData = $this->baseData();

   $asset = $this->pickAssetRandom();

   $publishings = $this->paginate($this->getPublishings, 12);

   return view('pages.home', compact('publishings', 'baseData', 'asset'));
}
```

Comment: Here you are doing a comparison. Please can you show where you are setting `$status` within the controller?

Comment: I didn't set $status. It's the response of Laravel Breeze. When Breeze sends an email successfully, $status becomes "password.send" and the condition in ternary becomes true. So it returns with $status. But I can't display it in Blade.

Comment: I understand but all you're are showing here is the comparison, not how you are passing this to the view. Does `dd($status)` show that `$status` is `true`? If it does we will need to see how you are passing this to the view. If possible, please show the entire controller method.

Comment: I don't pass it because as I understand Breeze do it while redirecting to back. Just like errors. If something goes wrong, we go back "withErrors" and I can display errors with $errors even if I don't pass the errors. So in my controller there is nothing about status or errors. You can see them in my question.

Comment: Were you able to fix displaying status message? Am facing same issue here but email submitted successful.

Answer (score 1):

The `$status` is being set in the `PasswordResetLinkController`.

Specifically:

```php
back()->with('status', __($status))
```

So, as you can see, it is returning the previous page and passing in `status`.

However, if `$status == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT` is false, then `$status` is not set, but the `$errors['email']` is. You can see this on the ternary condition in your code.

Try:

`dd($status == Password::REST_LINK_SENT);`

before the return statement on the controller, if you get false then there will be no `$status`, and you will get the `undefiened variable error`.

You can account for this in your view:

```
@if ($status) 
    {{ $status }} // A link was sent
@endif


// no link sent and here are the errors.
@if ($errors->any())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    {{ $error }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Laravel docs on this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passwords#resetting-the-password

Comment: While  $status returns undefiened, in controller ``` if ($status != Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) { dd(false) }``` isn't triggered. So as you can see they are equal and $status is still undefined.

Comment: Interesting. You are trying to display `$status` on the view that sent the request, and thus, the view that is returned from `back()`?

Comment: I think so because it's going back to the previous page.

Comment: And your certain that controller method is hit? Perhaps posting your view might shed more light.

Comment: Yes, I got email.

Comment: It should work then, all I can suggest is posting the relevant section of your web.php and view.

Answer (score 0):

Treat that `status` as a session and it will work

```
@if (session('status'))
    <span class="alert alert-success">{{ session('status') ?? ''}} </span>
@endif
```